# user get the admin permission when admin change level of user to admin in php

Tags: php

i have one clientadmin in my application so that clientadmin create one accesscode and he gave it to his users..

so his users take that accesscode and by using that they will register

so clientadmin can see all his users in his dashboard

so he has option to make one of his users to clientadmin

what i am trying to do is..when he make his user to clientadmin he can able to get all permissions of that particular clientadmin..

but now what happened in my application when i make the user to clientadmin

he can see only empty pages.he cant able to see all his(clientadmin) data in dashboard..

here its just changing the role.but it can't get able to get that particular clientadmin data

can anyone tell me the logic..how to do

Comment: Syntax error on line 17. /s
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i can't able to show all my code here what i have tried ..thats why i just told about my problem..

Comment: We don't need ALL your code. We need the specific parts of your code that are relevant for the problem.

Comment: i can't able to show some relevant code..if i show relevant code like some small part..no one can't understand..what s going where  we have to add our logic..

Comment: beacuse the logic is like that..if i want to show i have to show some min 50 lines of relevant code

Comment: if it is posssible can you please connect me to one chat group..so i can show you my code..

Comment: Well then I'm sorry, but we won't be able to help you. We don't have ANY information about your system. We don't know the structure of your database, we don't know what you've tried so far. We don't know what you mean with "empty page" ... -> A complete white page? Without ANY content?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155388/discussion-between-user200-and-twinfriends).

Comment: can you please connect me to chat i will explain there or come to this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155388/discussion-between-user200-and-twinfriends